# Running Karate UI tests with “driverTarget” in GitLab CI

Tags: docker, karate

Question was:
I would like to run Karate UI tests using the driverTarget options to test my Java Play app which is running locally during the same job with sbt run.

I have a simple assertion to check for a property but whenever the tests runs I keep getting "description":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null This is my karate-config.js:

```
if (env === 'ci') {
karate.log('using environment:', env);
karate.configure('driverTarget',
    {
        docker: 'justinribeiro/chrome-headless',
        showDriverLog: true
    });
}
```

This is my test scenario:

Scenario: test 1: some test
Given driver 'http://localhost:9000'

- waitUntil("document.readyState == 'complete'")
- match attribute('some selector', 'some attribute') == 'something'
  My guess is that because justinribeiro/chrome-headless is running in its own container, localhost:9000 is different in the container compared to what's running outside of it.

Is there any workaround for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

A docker container cannot talk to localhost port as per what was posted: "My guess is that because justinribeiro/chrome-headless is running in its own container, localhost:9000 is different in the container compared to what's running outside of it."

To get around this and have docker container communicate with running app on localhost port **use command *host.docker.internal***

Change to make:
*From: Given driver 'http://localhost:9000'*.
**To: Given driver 'http://host.docker.internal:9000'**

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, I was able to use the ptrthomas/karate-chrome image in CI (GITLAB) by inserting the following inside my gitlab-ci.yml file

```
  stages:
    - uiTest

  featureOne:
    stage: uiTest
    image: docker:latest
    cache:
      paths:
        - .m2/repository/
    services:
      - docker:dind
script:
      - docker run --name karate --rm --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -v "$PWD":/karate -v 
"$HOME"/.m2:/root/.m2 ptrthomas/karate-chrome &
      - sleep 45
      - docker exec -w /karate karate mvn test -DargLine='-Dkarate.env=docker' Dtest=testParallel
    allow_failure: true
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - reports
        - ${CLOUD_APP_NAME}.log


my karate-config.js file looks like
    if (karate.env == 'docker') {
        karate.configure('driver', {
            type: 'chrome',
            showDriverLog: true,
            start: false,
            beforeStart: 'supervisorctl start ffmpeg',
            afterStop: 'supervisorctl stop ffmpeg',
            videoFile: '/tmp/karate.mp4'
        });
    }
```